# Manage dynamic routes with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have an AngularJS app (Angular v1) that is all working with a secure login. Users not authenticated can can only see the login page, the forgotten password page and the cookie policy.

I am using `ngRoute` like this:

```
    $routeProvider
    .when('/login:param', {
        templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })

    /* ... other routes ... */

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
```

Now, I would like to redirect the users to dashboard if they are logged in without the ability to see all the "public routes" (== routes that users can see without authentication); and redirect them to the login page if they are not logged in.

To do so, I am performing a check in Angular `run` function and listening to the `$locationChangeStart` event:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        if (routeClean($location.path()) && AuthenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
            $location.url(DASHBOARD);
        } else {
            $location.url(LOGIN);
        }
    });
```

where `DASHBOARD` is a constant that contains the route to `/dashboard` and `LOGIN` is a constant that contains the route to `/login`.

Before proceeding, I have a couple of questions:

- **is `run` the correct place to perform this check?** (even if it is working, maybe this check should be placed elsewhere)
- **what is the best practice to achieve this?**

In this check, `AuthenticationService` is a service that is authenticating the users, whilst `routeClean` is a function that is checking if the route is inside an array:

```
    var routeClean = function (route) {
        for (var i = 0; i < CLEAN_ROUTES.length; i++) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(CLEAN_ROUTES[i]);
            var bool = pattern.test(route);
            if (bool)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
```

Where `CLEAN_ROUTES` is an array where there are all the "public routes".

```
    CLEAN_ROUTES = [
        '/login',
        '/forgotten-password',
        '/verify-code',
        '/reset-password',
        '/cookie-policy'
    ]
```

So, here the final questions:

- **Is there a smarter way to check the "public routes" with Angular?**
- If, for example, I want to show a *different login template for the users*, something like:

  ```
  /login?user=client
  /login?user=seller
  /login?user=editor
  /login?user=admin
  ```

**is there a way where `ngRoute` can do that dynamically?**

What I mean with this latest question is: if, for example, when the users log out the app, I redirect them to the `LOGIN` constant (that is the general route for the login page `/login`), *is there a way where I can differentiate the seller, the client, etc so I can redirect them to the proper login template/page?*

Answer (score 0):

IMO [$httpProvider.interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is the most efficient way.

In ngRoute you can use -

$routeProvider -> 'route' -> [resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) property

Comment: So you are saying that I should use use ```interceptors``` inside the resolve option in the definition of the routes, correct? This also mean that the check for the clean route should go inside the resolve, correct?